# 困っている usage / different meanings depending on context?

Tags: usage

> 私は困っている。

I've seen the sentence translated as "I am in trouble", however depending on the context is it possible that it also could mean "I am troubled" or "I am worried"?

Comment: 困る・困っている can be translated in many ways: [困る in プログレッシブ and E-DIC](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/27133/meaning/m0u/) ・  [困っている in 英辞郎](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%9B%B0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B) ・  [困っている in Weblio例文](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E5%9B%B0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B)

Comment: Thanks, the examples are helpful.  So my other translations are probably valid

Answer (score 2):

困る / 困っている / 困った can be translated in many ways:

I am in trouble / difficulty; I am having a hard time; I am (being) troubled / stuck / annoyed / bothered / distressed / embarrassed / perplexed / at a loss / in need / in inconvenience, etc...

So yes, I think it is possible that it also could mean "I am troubled" "I am worried", depending on the context, although we more commonly say (～が)[心配]{しんぱい}だ / (～を)心配している to mean "I am worried / anxious / concerned (about...)"